# setting up my family

Tags: apps, parental-control

It's been days that I have this phone I can't even download an app it keeps on telling me to set up my family please people help me set up my family  I your help.

I wanted to download whatsapp but it tells me the same thing  plz help me guys.

Comment: Please guys please answer my question I just need answers for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you under the age of 18? In that case, you need to add yourself as a child to one of your parents' account. You can do this by referring to this article: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/apps/set-up-my-family-for-windows-phone. And if you don't want to do this, the simple solution is to create a new account and sign in with that or change your birthday in your Outlook settings which can be done by referring to this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/child-birthdate-microsoft-account